# Powerpc: boost cross platform compilation under windows

Tags: boost, powerpc

I cannot finish building of a boost_1_41_0 for powerpc603 under windows using cygwin.

I run cygwin under windows, and go to location of boost_1_41_0 in console. Next I call ./bootstrap.sh -with-toolset=powerpc
(of course I have preliminary added all necessary lines into bootstrap.sh и build.sh with a path to a powerpc compiler)

It exit with the following log:

```
###
###Using 'powerpc' toolset.
###

rm -rf bootstrap
mkdir bootstrap
c:/cygwin/opt/crosstool/gcc-4.1.0-glibc-2.3.6/powerpc-603e-linux-gnu/bin/powerpc-603e-linux-gnu-gcc.exe -o bootstrap/jam0 command.c compile.c debug.c expand.c glob.c hash.c hdrmacro.c headers.c jam.c jambase.c jamgram.c lists.c make.c make1.c newstr.c option.c output.c parse.c pathunix.c pathvms.c regexp.c rules.c scan.c search.c subst.c timestamp.c variable.c modules.c strings.c filesys.c builtins.c pwd.c class.c native.c w32_getreg.c modules/set.c modules/path.c modules/regex.c modules/property-set.c modules/sequence.c modules/order.c execunix.c fileunix.c
./bootstrap/jam0 -f build.jam --toolset=powerpc --toolset-root=c:/cygwin/opt/crosstool/gcc-4.1.0-glibc-2.3.6/powerpc-603e-linux-gnu/powerpc-603e-linux-gnu clean
**./bootstrap/jam0: ./bootstrap/jam0: cannot execute binary file**
```

I really see a file jam0 there.
Its properties are following:

```
Class: ELF32
Encoding: **Big endian**
ELFVersion: Executable file
Machine:**PowerPC**
Version:current
Entry...
.... and so on.
```

So, the intermediate file jam0 seem to be prepared. And now toolchain wants to call it, but cygwin does not recognize it as linux executable (I believe it, since this file is compiled for powerpc603 architecture, not for x86)

And now I stuck with this, what to do next? I know some programmers build boost for powerpc?

**UPD:**
I got bjam.exe finally.
now I try following:
1) placed user-config.jam with the following content:

```
using gcc : ppc : c:/cygwin/opt/crosstool/gcc-4.1.0-glibc-2.3.6/powerpc-603e-linux-gnu/powerpc-603e-linux-gnu/bin/g++.exe ;
```

2) command line for bjam which I call from cmd under windows:

```
bjam toolset=gcc-ppc --with-thread --with-system --debug-configuration stage
```

**What I get as a result is always this:**

```
    ...failed gcc.compile.c++ bin.v2\libs\wave\build\gcc-ppc\release\link-static\threading-multi\cpplexer\re2clex\cpp_re.o...
...skipped <pbin.v2\libs\wave\build\gcc-ppc\release\link-static\threading-multi>libboost_wave-gcc-mt-1_41.lib(clean) for lack of <pbin.v2\libs\wave\bu
ild\gcc-ppc\release\link-static\threading-multi>instantiate_cpp_exprgrammar.o...
...skipped <pbin.v2\libs\wave\build\gcc-ppc\release\link-static\threading-multi>libboost_wave-gcc-mt-1_41.lib for lack of <pbin.v2\libs\wave\build\gcc
-ppc\release\link-static\threading-multi>instantiate_cpp_exprgrammar.o...
...skipped <pstage\lib>libboost_wave-gcc-mt-1_41.lib for lack of <pbin.v2\libs\wave\build\gcc-ppc\release\link-static\threading-multi>libboost_wave-gc
c-mt-1_41.lib...
...skipped <pstage\lib>libboost_date_time-gcc-mt.lib for lack of <pstage\lib>libboost_date_time-gcc-mt-1_41.lib...
...skipped <pstage\lib>libboost_system-gcc-mt.lib for lack of <pstage\lib>libboost_system-gcc-mt-1_41.lib...
...skipped <pstage\lib>libboost_filesystem-gcc-mt.lib for lack of <pstage\lib>libboost_filesystem-gcc-mt-1_41.lib...
...skipped <pstage\lib>libboost_regex-gcc-mt.lib for lack of <pstage\lib>libboost_regex-gcc-mt-1_41.lib...
...skipped <pstage\lib>libboost_graph-gcc-mt.lib for lack of <pstage\lib>libboost_graph-gcc-mt-1_41.lib...
...skipped <pstage\lib>libboost_iostreams-gcc-mt.lib for lack of <pstage\lib>libboost_iostreams-gcc-mt-1_41.lib...
...skipped <pstage\lib>libboost_math_tr1-gcc-mt.lib for lack of <pstage\lib>libboost_math_tr1-gcc-mt-1_41.lib...
...skipped <pstage\lib>libboost_math_tr1f-gcc-mt.lib for lack of <pstage\lib>libboost_math_tr1f-gcc-mt-1_41.lib...
...skipped <pstage\lib>libboost_math_tr1l-gcc-mt.lib for lack of <pstage\lib>libboost_math_tr1l-gcc-mt-1_41.lib...
...skipped <pstage\lib>libboost_math_c99-gcc-mt.lib for lack of <pstage\lib>libboost_math_c99-gcc-mt-1_41.lib...
...skipped <pstage\lib>libboost_math_c99f-gcc-mt.lib for lack of <pstage\lib>libboost_math_c99f-gcc-mt-1_41.lib...
...skipped <pstage\lib>libboost_math_c99l-gcc-mt.lib for lack of <pstage\lib>libboost_math_c99l-gcc-mt-1_41.lib...
...skipped <pstage\lib>libboost_program_options-gcc-mt.lib for lack of <pstage\lib>libboost_program_options-gcc-mt-1_41.lib...
...skipped <pstage\lib>libboost_serialization-gcc-mt.lib for lack of <pstage\lib>libboost_serialization-gcc-mt-1_41.lib...
...skipped <pstage\lib>libboost_wserialization-gcc-mt.lib for lack of <pstage\lib>libboost_wserialization-gcc-mt-1_41.lib...
...skipped <pstage\lib>libboost_signals-gcc-mt.lib for lack of <pstage\lib>libboost_signals-gcc-mt-1_41.lib...
...skipped <pstage\lib>libboost_prg_exec_monitor-gcc-mt.lib for lack of <pstage\lib>libboost_prg_exec_monitor-gcc-mt-1_41.lib...
...skipped <pstage\lib>libboost_test_exec_monitor-gcc-mt.lib for lack of <pstage\lib>libboost_test_exec_monitor-gcc-mt-1_41.lib...
...skipped <pstage\lib>libboost_unit_test_framework-gcc-mt.lib for lack of <pstage\lib>libboost_unit_test_framework-gcc-mt-1_41.lib...
...skipped <pstage\lib>libboost_thread-gcc-mt.lib for lack of <pstage\lib>libboost_thread-gcc-mt-1_41.lib...
...skipped <pstage\lib>libboost_wave-gcc-mt.lib for lack of <pstage\lib>libboost_wave-gcc-mt-1_41.lib...
...failed updating 231 targets...
...skipped 420 targets...
...updated 89 targets...
```

**failed gcc.compile.c++** is an event for most of the files

after all this, stage/lib is empty, of course.
**what should I do next?**

Comment: Bjam is used to build boost, so you shouldn't be cross compiling that. The simplest is probably to build it separately.

Comment: ah so... do I have to compile bjam with .... some other compiler, supported by cygwin (or one provided with cygwin), and after that to run bjam from cygwin to build finally boost? I am not sure if I know how to make this final step. No parameters found for this step.

Comment: Or build bjam.exe under windows, and configure it to build boost for powerpc?

Comment: 1) I got bjam! thanks for help with this point!